# Why isn't my tablet media query activating?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

**Problem**

I have three media queries, one for Mobile, Tablet and Desktop screen sizes. All were working fine, until i must have done something that has stopped the Tablet media query from working/activating?

I know its not working as navigation menu is set to display differently from the other two queries.

Each should be displayed as picture below.

**Phone**

[image]

**Tablet**

[image]

**Desktop**

[image]

**What actually happens?**

Upon resizing browser window the tablet media query is skipped, switching straight to the mobile query from the desktop.

**Live Example**

[My Testing Server](http://cundypi.servehttp.com/BassClef/fluid.html)

**My HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="fluid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="title">
  <h1>Bass Clef Photography</h1>
</div>
<div id="tagline">Passion 4 Live Music &amp; Passion 4 Photography</div>
<div id="tabsContainer">
<div id="centerContainer">
 <div class='tab zero'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="BassClef.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
    <div class='tab one'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Music Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab two'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab three'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab four'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab five'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS**

```
   @charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
}
/*
    Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
    ----------------------------------
    dw-num-cols-mobile:     5;
    dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
    dw-num-cols-desktop:    10;
    dw-gutter-percentage:   25;

    Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
    http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

    and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
    http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

#tabsContainer {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#centerContainer {
    width: 230px;
    height: 280px;
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 200px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li #active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    clear: both;
}
.tab.one {
    width: 220px auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 87.36%;
    padding-left: 1.82%;
    padding-right: 1.82%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#title {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
#tagline {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #d3701e;
}
}



/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */


@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 90.675%;
    padding-left: 1.1625%;
    padding-right: 1.1625%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#title {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#tagline {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#tabsContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#centerContainer {
    width: 460px;
    height: 150px;
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li #active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    clear: none;
}
.tab.one {
    width: 220px auto;
    font-size: 24px;
}
}


/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 88.2%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.9%;
    padding-right: 0.9%;
    margin: auto;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#title {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
#tagline {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
#tabsContainer {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#centerContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: auto;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li #active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    clear: none;
}
.tab.one {
    width: 190px;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
}
```

Any help or pointers to the right direction would be greatly appreciated. This is my first attempt at a "responsive" Website so i'm guessing i may have made some mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra curly brace at the end of your mobile layout styles. After #tagline. Remove that and it should be good.

Comment: They are not extra, they are closing the media query. ;) Sry i thought he mean the last one, yes he is right.

Comment: Your mobile layout styles do not have a media query.

Comment: An extra question on the off chance you may know why? Do you know why there is a gap between the first and second Divs? There isn't any between the rest?

Comment: Some elements have margin and padding by default. Set your h1 element margin to 0 and that will get rid of that.

Comment: Thank you once again @TheLawrence, worked perfectly. Think i'll apply a reset CSS to my CSS.